# How to count number of nodes in XSLT with various conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML, based on which I am creating a text file output. In the trailer record I have to count the total number of records in the output file. The logic used to create output file from XML is if the `PreTaxAmt`,or `MatchAmt`, or `RothAmt` for each report entry has a value greater than zero, there is one line created in output. If the `Loanamt` is greater than zero for each report entry then  the record is outputted in a separate line. Please suggest me how can I use the count function to create the total counts of the line in the XSLT. I am pasting below what I have tried.

```
< Report_Entry>
    < Participant_ID>033709571</ Participant_ID>
    < Workers>
        < FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</ FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        < Last_Name>Vani</ Last_Name>
        < First_Name>Mehul</ First_Name>
        < Middle_Name>N</ Middle_Name>
        < Rehire_Date_1>2013-04-15-07:00</ Rehire_Date_1>
    </ Workers>
    < End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</ End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    < PreTaxAmt>100.8</ PreTaxAmt>
    < MatchAmt>100.8</ MatchAmt>
    < RothAmt>0</ RothAmt>
    < LoanAmt>80</ LoanAmt>
</ Report_Entry>
< Report_Entry>
    < Participant_ID>037686040</ Participant_ID>
    < Workers>
        < FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</ FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        < Last_Name>Phonevilay</ Last_Name>
        < First_Name>Somsaath</ First_Name>
        < Gender_Code>1</ Gender_Code>
        < Rehire_Date_1>2012-06-18-07:00</ Rehire_Date_1>
    </ Workers>
    < End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</ End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    < PreTaxAmt>61.81</ PreTaxAmt>
    < MatchAmt>61.81</ MatchAmt>
    < RothAmt>0</ RothAmt>
    < LoanAmt>76</ LoanAmt>
</ Report_Entry>
< Report_Entry>
    < Participant_ID>043781931</ Participant_ID>
    < Workers>
        < FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</ FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
        < Last_Name>Ousouphan</ Last_Name>
        < First_Name>Phouangmala</ First_Name>
        < Gender_Code>2</ Gender_Code>
        < Rehire_Date_1>2001-03-20-08:00</ Rehire_Date_1>
    </ Workers>
    < End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</ End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    < PreTaxAmt>84.19</ PreTaxAmt>
    < MatchAmt>0</ MatchAmt>
    < RothAmt>75</ RothAmt>
    < LoanAmt>90</ LoanAmt>
</ Report_Entry>
```

**The XSLT code that I have used is below and it should output 6.**

```
<xsl:if test="( PreTaxAmt != 0) or( MatchAmt != 0) or ( RothAmt != 0) ">
        <xsl:variable name="recordCount">
        <xsl:value-of select=" 
            count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PreTaxAmt) 
            "/>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if  test=" LoanAmt != 0"> 
                <xsl:variable name="recordCount1">
                    <xsl:value-of select=" 
                        count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ LoanAmt) 
                        "/>

                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="var3" select="number($recordCount) + number($recordCount1)"/>
            </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming that you repair your text object to be well-formed XML by**

- removing all spaces from the tag names
- adding a `Report_Data` root element

**as follows:**

```
<Report_Data>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>033709571</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
      <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
      <Last_Name>Vani</Last_Name>
      <First_Name>Mehul</First_Name>
      <Middle_Name>N</Middle_Name>
      <Rehire_Date_1>2013-04-15-07:00</Rehire_Date_1>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>100.8</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>100.8</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>80</LoanAmt>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>037686040</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
      <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
      <Last_Name>Phonevilay</Last_Name>
      <First_Name>Somsaath</First_Name>
      <Gender_Code>1</Gender_Code>
      <Rehire_Date_1>2012-06-18-07:00</Rehire_Date_1>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>61.81</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>61.81</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>0</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>76</LoanAmt>
  </Report_Entry>
  <Report_Entry>
    <Participant_ID>043781931</Participant_ID>
    <Workers>
      <FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>1</FULL_PART_Time_Indicator>
      <Last_Name>Ousouphan</Last_Name>
      <First_Name>Phouangmala</First_Name>
      <Gender_Code>2</Gender_Code>
      <Rehire_Date_1>2001-03-20-08:00</Rehire_Date_1>
    </Workers>
    <End_Date_from_Pay_Period>2016-01-03-08:00</End_Date_from_Pay_Period>
    <PreTaxAmt>84.19</PreTaxAmt>
    <MatchAmt>0</MatchAmt>
    <RothAmt>75</RothAmt>
    <LoanAmt>90</LoanAmt>
  </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

**Then the following XSLT,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Report_Data">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(Report_Entry[   number(PreTaxAmt) > 0
                                             or number(MatchAmt) > 0
                                             or number(RothAmt) > 0])
                          + count(Report_Entry[number(LoanAmt) > 0])"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will output `6` as requested.**

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. It worked! Initially , I did try something like the code you have mentioned but my format was not correct.